# Unable to see text for inactive tab using createMaterialBottomTab and React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm very new to React and am trying to set the color for the text and other styles for the inactive tabs on my bottom bar but a few hours on it already and not able to make it work as the text doesn't appear unless it's the selected tab. I'm using **createMaterialBottomTab**.

[image]

[image]

This is my entire screen if I can get any help please:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Platform, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs'

import HeadlinesScreen from '../screens/HeadlinesScreen'
import IrelandScreen from '../screens/IrelandScreen'
import TechnologyScreen from '../screens/TechnologyScreen'

const defaultStackNavOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#4a148c'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
}

const NewsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Headlines: HeadlinesScreen,
        Ireland: IrelandScreen,
        Technology: TechnologyScreen
    })

const HeadLinesNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Headlines: HeadlinesScreen
    }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarColor: 'green'
    }
})

const IrelandNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Ireland: IrelandScreen
    }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarColor: 'red'
    }
})

const TechnologyNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Technology: TechnologyScreen
    }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarColor: 'purple'
    }
})

const config = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Headlines',
    shifting: true,
    activeColor: 'black',
    inactiveColor: 'black',
    activeTintColor: 'black',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    labeled: true,
}

const NewsAllNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    Headlines: HeadLinesNavigator,
    Ireland: IrelandNavigator,
    Technology: TechnologyNavigator,
}, config)

export default createAppContainer(NewsAllNavigator)
```

Thank you very much.

**UPDATED**

I noticed now that I **can see** items if I **add icons to the bottom bar**. Still not the labels unless the item is selected. I guess this may be the default behaviour but not sure it can be overwritten?

```
const HeadLinesNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Headlines: HeadlinesScreen
    }, {
    headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions,
    navigationOptions: {
        // tabBarIcon: <TabItem label='Headlines' />,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <View>
                <FontAwesome name='newspaper-o' size={25} color='white' />
            </View>
        ),
        tabBarColor: 'green',
    }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The option you search for is: shifting={false}. Then you get all labels shown below the icons.

```
<TabNavigator.Navigator
            initialRouteName="myScreen"
            shifting={false}
...
            <TabNavigator.Screen
...
            />
</TabNavigator.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  this syntax for creating bottomTabNavigation from react-navigation v5. Also note to import screen that i have used in code.

Link to official docs is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator)

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

const BottomNavigator = () => {
  const BottomNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <BottomNavigation.Navigator>
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Exam"
        component={ExamStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="book" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomNavigation.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="settings" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomNavigation.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomNavigator;
```

### package.json

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.5",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
"react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
"react-native-webview": "7.4.3"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm using material bottom bar and would like to stick with it if possible as it has some other features that are useful to my project.